# How to exclude single checks from clang-tidy file?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Let's talk about this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "started " << argv[0] << " with " << argc << " params." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

We have a minimal `.clang-tidy` file which looks like this:

```
Checks:
    '-*,
    cppcoreguidelines-*,
    -cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-pointer-arithmetic'

WarningsAsErrors:
    '*'
```

Even though I get the following warning:

```
src/main.cpp:5:30: error: do not use pointer arithmetic [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-pointer-arithmetic,-warnings-as-errors]
  std::cout << "started " << argv[0] << " with " << argc << " params." << std::endl;
                             ^
```

I don't want to mess around with `NOLINT` in my code and I don't want to add some additional flags to the `CMakeLists.txt` file just because of `clang-tidy`.

Is there a clean way, to mask some single checks in the `.clang-tidy` file?

I'm using gcc/g++ and clang-tidy in version 6.0.0 on Linux. I'm aware of [How to disable a clang-tidy check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474683/how-to-disable-a-clang-tidy-check) - but it doesn't answer my question and the duplicate link is simply wrong.

Comment: I'd also like to know, if you figure it out! Using clang-tidy with Meson, and adding inline checks is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I think the problem had to do with glob expansion order. Originally, the `Checks` line in my `.clang-tidy` looked like this:

```
Checks: 'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*,*'
```

I wanted to disable the `altera-unroll-loops` diagnostic. The fix was to add it after that sneaky glob-all at the end:

```
Checks: 'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*,*,-altera-unroll-loops'
```

Initially, I had it placed before the `*`, which, I think, caused it to be overridden. I also had no problem with it being split across multiple lines, like you have above.